# How can I compile a program using Clang from standard input?

Tags: compilation, clang, stdin

I have a program coming from standard input. I would like to compile it. Is this possible and if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe input to the compiler with the `-` argument.

To compile a simple program (replace `programsource` with something that outputs the program source, such as an `echo` or some other program generator) as an example

```
programsource | clang -x c - -o a.out
```

You'll need to specify the language using the [-x option](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-x-language) (note this option is case sensitive). If you don't you'll get an error that

```
error: -E or -x required when input is from standard input
```

You can add other command line arguments as necessary.